# Un-subdivide problem

Tags: subdivision-surface

I'm new to Blender. I'm modelling my first head. I accidentally saved it with the sub divide on and tried to figure out how to unsubdivide. I found decimate, but that only worked in object mode. Then in edit mode, I tried unsubdivide from the Edge menu, but then the head was distorted like it had been in a fire accident! I had the geometry I wanted back in object mode but not in edit mode. :(

Comment: Decimate will alter your mesh in both object and edit mode - the changes are only visible from object mode (by default) until you apply the modifier. So, use Decimate to get your mesh the way you like (I recommend viewing it in object mode - wireframe), and then apply the modifier. If you enter edit mode after that you'll see the mesh geometry in edit mode is the same as its geometry in object mode.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. Looks fine in object mode, but as soon as I hit apply it distorts.

Comment: Strange... (with the object selected in object mode) try `Ctrl+A > Scale` (apply scale) before applying the modifier.

Answer (score 0):

So from this question I'm guessing you've already applied the subdivision surface modifier by accident. If it looks distorted when you are using the decimate modifier try doing Ctrl+A > All Transform then apply it again, it should work out properly.